# Strange behavior with multiple documents when using composite templates

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

This is with the Rest api. We're seeing something interesting here with our implementation. I create a composite template for each document in the envelope, so if there were 4 documents, there would be 4 composite templates. Suppose I have 5 documents in my envelope, each with one signing tab. What we are seeing is that when the recipient goes to process the envelope, they need to click 5 times on the signing tab on each document to have the document completely processed. If the envelope had 4 documents, it would be 4 times per signing tab. It seems to be tied in with the number of documents in the envelope. This doesn't sound like behavior we want. What could we be doing wrong?

Here is the JSON being sent:

```
 "compositeTemplates": [
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "1",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "1",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "BAT SDTwo",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116945",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "SpouseF SpouseL",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116946",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Spouse_CoOwnerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
      },

      }
    }
  ],
  "document": {
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "e Bookmarks and Tags.pdf",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",

    "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
  }
},
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "2",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "2",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "BAT SDTwo",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116945",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "SpouseF SpouseL",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116946",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Spouse_CoOwnerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
      },

    }
  ],
  "document": {
    "documentId": "2",
    "name": "e Bookmarks and Tags II.pdf",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",

    "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
  }
},
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "3",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "3",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "BAT SDTwo",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116945",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "SpouseF SpouseL",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116946",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Spouse_CoOwnerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
      },

    }
  ],
  "document": {
    "documentId": "3",
    "name": "e Bookmarks and Tags Embedded.pdf",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",

    "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
  }
},
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "4",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "4",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "BAT SDTwo",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116945",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "SpouseF SpouseL",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116946",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Spouse_CoOwnerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
      },

    }
  ],
  "document": {
    "documentId": "4",
    "name": "e Static.pdf",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",

    "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
  }
},
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "5",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "5",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "BAT SDTwo",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116945",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "SpouseF SpouseL",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116946",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Spouse_CoOwnerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
      },

    }
  ],
  "document": {
    "documentId": "5",
    "name": "e Static II.pdf",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",

    "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
  }
},
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "6",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "6",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "BAT SDTwo",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116945",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "SpouseF SpouseL",
            "email": "ashish.dave@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "6116946",
            "accessCode": "4792989",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Spouse_CoOwnerName",
            "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the  document(s)",
              "emailBody": "Hello,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the Cartus document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
            }
          }
        ],
        "certifiedDeliveries": []
      },

    }
  ],
  "document": {
    "documentId": "6",
    "name": "e Static Embedded.pdf",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",

    "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
  }
}
```

],

Comment: Can you please post your request JSON.

Comment: I took a very straightforward approach with our wrapper because we were still learning about templates and how to accomplish what we needed to do. I also went under the erroneous assumption that you could only have one document per composite template. For most of our envelopes, we will be having maybe 8 or 10 documents, and possibly only 1 template for all these documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server template you are using has anchor tabs.  This is creating duplicate tabs on top of already existing tabs. The scope of the Anchor tabs is at envelope level, so if you are specifying 5 composite templates then the anchor tabs in each template will apply for the entire envelope.

During the signing ceremony you might be clicking on 5 different signature tabs which are on top of each other, but thinking that the same Tab has to be clicked 5 times.

Try using Fixed positioned tabs instead of Anchor tabs. That will resolve the duplicate tabs issue.

Comment: I'm afraid we are committed to using the Anchor tabs. At least I know what the behavior is now.